# How to properly add conditional class to Alpine JS x-for template?

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I'm trying to iterate through a loop and add a conditional class to each element above 4 items for some resposive styling with tailwindcss.

Previously I had the loop adding in some other class, which was working fine:

```
<template x-for="(card, index ) in cards" :key="index">
    <div class="w-40 h-64"
         x-modal="card"
         :class="card.someOtherClass"
    >
        <div class="card-content" :id="'card-' + card.id">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But then I needed to add in a conditional statement to check if the number of items was above 4.
I looked at the following previously asked question:

[AlpineJS: How can I add a class to an element conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975048/alpinejs-how-can-i-add-a-class-to-an-element-conditionally)

This suggests to use `{ 'class-name': statement }`, so I've done the following:

```
<template x-for="(card, index ) in cards" :key="index">
    <div class="w-40 h-64"
         x-modal="card"
         :class="[card.someOtherClass,
             {'bg-green-500':  index > 3 },
          ]"
        >
        <div class="card-content" :id="'card-' + card.id">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I get this `<div class="w-40 h-64 some-other-class [object Object]">` passed to the relevant HTML in the browser. How do I get the relevant values from this object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the `card.someOtherClass` a variable property name, surround it in square brackets. Then, set it to true so it's always added to the class list.

```
:class="{[card.someOtherClass]: true, 'bg-green-500': index > 3 }"
```

Answer (score 7):

Example of changing style on-lick:

```
<div x-data="{ show: false }">
      <button @click="show = !show" :class="{ 'active': show }">
    Toggle Button
    </button>
    
</div>
```

css:

```
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/bubnenkoff/pen/RwLoBXd

Answer (score 1):

This format works for me and gives the benefit of using the documented Alpine style for multiple types of :class, and an option for an alternative class if index <= 3

```
<template x-for="(card, index ) in cards" :key="index">
<div class="w-40 h-64"
     x-modal="card"
     :class="[
         card.someOtherClass,
         index > 3 ? 'bg-green-500' : '',
      ]"
    >
    <div class="card-content" :id="'card-' + card.id">
    </div>
</div>
```